# Laravel - How to Pass JSON value from dropdown as route parameter

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 I have this JSON get request code in the controller:

```
public function findIdentity(Request $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $identity = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id',$request->id)->first();
    return response()->json([
        'identity' => $identity->id
    ]);        
}
```

View blade:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#identity', function() {
      var air_id = $(this).val();
      var a = $(this).parent();
      var op = "";
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{ route('
        get.identities.all ') }}',
        data: {
          'id': air_id
        },
        dataType: 'json', //return data will be json


        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data.identity);
          $('#identity_id').val(data.identity);

        },
        error: function() {

        }
      });
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
  <label class="control-label"> Performance Period:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select id="identity" name="identity_id" class="form-control">
      <option value="">--- Select Performance Period ---</option>
      @foreach ($identities as $ids => $name)
      <option value="{{ $ids }}" {{ request( 'identity_id')==$ids ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="identity_id" class="form-control">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="search">Search</button>
    <form action="{{ route('performance_dashboard', $id) }}" method="get" target="_blank" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" name="viewIdentity"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> View Identity</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

route:

```
Route::get('get/findIdentity','HomeController@findIdentity')->name('get.identities.all');
```

From all the codes above, I am trying to get the id of the dropdown (select option) in the view blade into the route parameter.

How do I pass #identity_id as the parameter #id in:

```
{{ route('performance_dashboard', $id) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to set javascript response in php variable, but one thing you can do is mentioned below :

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="search">Search</button>
    <form action="{{ route('performance_dashboard') }}" method="get" target="_blank" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <input type="hidden" id="identity_id" class="form-control"/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" name="viewIdentity"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> View Identity</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in controller you can simpally get **indentity_id**.